# What is best way to create popup menu like in eclipse on Ctrl+F6?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I want to create popup menu exactly the same as in eclipse on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

It should have `JScrollBar` and list of Strings where each item has small border.

I have idea to use `JDialog` but how to make it not display border and close buttons but only `JList` with scroll bar?

Thank you!

Comment: How will you close it, without a close button? Also you can use `setUndecorated(true)` for no frame border

Comment: You might want to add a screenshot of that menu for those not using Eclipse

Comment: And edit your question to say what feature(s) of the eclipse popup you want to emulate.

Comment: so what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most straightforward way is to use the `JPopupMenu` class. You can add any `JComponent` to a `JPopupMenu`, not just `JMenuItem`s.

Here's a button which when clicked, shows a `JList` in a popup without any close buttons, just with a scroll bar. Wherever the popup (the `JList`) loses focus, the popup will be automatically closed.

```
final JButton b = new JButton("Press me");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            model.addElement(i + ".");
        final JList<String> l = new JList<>(model);

        final JPopupMenu pm = new JPopupMenu();
        final JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(l);
        // pm.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 300));
        pm.add(sp);
        pm.show(b, 0, 0);
    }
});
```